# using "AND" and "OR" in an SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I am trying to optimize a query. There are three different lookups in the table, which i think, are not required.

This is the original query, which i want to optimize.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(productid) FROM q_products
      WHERE visibility=1 and status=0 AND productid IN (productidList)
        UNION ALL 
      SELECT DISTINCT(q_products.productid) FROM q_products,q_product_apply_access 
        WHERE q_products.productid=q_product_apply_access.productid 
        AND q_product_apply_access.partnerid='partnerid'
        AND q_product_apply_access.apply_status=0 
        AND q_products.visibility=3 AND q_products.status=0 
        AND q_products.productid IN (productidList)
        UNION ALL
      SELECT DISTINCT(q_products.productid) FROM q_products,q_product_aff_access 
        WHERE q_products.productid=q_product_aff_access.productid 
        AND q_product_aff_access.accid='accountid' 
        AND q_products.visibility=2 AND q_products.status=0 
        AND q_products.productid IN (productidList)
```

Let me walk you all through this query,

1) I am selecting distinct `productid` from `q_products` which have `visibility=1` and `status=0` and which are also in `productidList`

2) I am now selecting distinct `productid` from `q_products` and checking if same `productid` is present in another table `q_product_apply_access`, if so, then checking if `q_product_apply_access.partnerid` is same as given to us and also if `q_product_apply_access.apply_status` is 0 and then again, checking if those `productid`s are in `productidList`.

3) It does similar things and at the end checks again if `productid`s are in `productidList`.

**My idea to optimize was is to do the following way** ->

1) select all `productids` from `q_products` which are in my productidList.

2) check if those `productids` are in tables `q_product_apply_access` and `q_product_aff_access` and if yes, then their subsequent conditions are fulfilled.

3) when all this is done, i check which of those have `q_products.visibility IN (1,2,3)` and `q_products.status=0`.

I think in that way i can minimize lookups in the table and my query would be queried in minimal subset of productidList which may contain only upto 20-30 rows.

Here is my code for that , but I am not getting the correct answer. Can anyone tell me how I can do it? or How I should apply nested loops here?

```
SELECT DISTINCT(productid) 
        FROM q_products as oc, 
        q_product_apply_access  as ocaa, 
        q_product_aff_access as ocfa
        WHERE productid IN (productidList)
          AND (
            (oc.productid=ocaa.productid 
            AND ocaa.affiliateid='partnerid'
            AND ocaa.apply_status=0) 
            OR
            (oc.productid=ocfa.productid 
            AND ocfa.accid='accountid')
            )
          and status=0
          AND visibility IN (1,2,3)
```

Comment: When you say "not getting the correct answer", I'm assuming you mean that the results are not the same?

Comment: yup! exactly! plus the table is taking alot more time to lookup.

Comment: So, if a product as `visibility = 1` you want it, regardless of its existence in other tables. If its `visibility = 2`, you only want it if it's ALSO in the `q_product_aff_access` table (regardless of whether or not it also happens to be in the other one), and if its `visibility = 3` then you only want it if its ALSO in the `q_product_apply_access` table. Sound about right?

Comment: yes , i need `visibility=1` regardless of other tables, but `q_products.status=0` is a necessary condition.

Answer (score 1):

The title of your question:

> using "AND" and "OR" in an SQL query

Might be more accurately defined as:

> Will using "AND" and/or "OR" statements help this query run faster?

And, the short answer is, **NO**.-- the optimizations will probably need to be done elsewhere.

So, the long answer:

After looking at this for a while, the requirements 'baked into' the original query prevent logical `JOIN`s from speeding anything up. Your best bet to get this to run faster is to utilize indexes on the tables being referenced. My original answer was using inner-selects, but didn't meet the requirements. By *requirements*, I mean the necessity of returning a list of unique productids from the productid table meeting three different and distinct criteria.

That said, I would re-write the original query into something more readable, using `JOIN` statements and aliases for readability *(note the absence of `DISTINCT` -- the `UNION` ensures unique records out of all 3 result sets)*:

```
SELECT p.productid
FROM q_products p
WHERE visibility = 1
  AND status = 0
  AND productid IN (productIdList)

UNION

SELECT p.productid
FROM q_products p
JOIN q_product_apply_access paa ON paa.productid = p.productid
WHERE paa.partnerid = 'partnerid'
  AND paa.apply_status = 0
  AND p.visibility = 3
  AND p.status = 0
  AND p.productid IN (productidList)

UNION

SELECT p.productid
FROM q_products p
JOIN q_product_aff_access paf ON paf.productid = p.productid
WHERE paf.accid = 'accountid'
  AND p.visibility = 2
  AND p.status = 0
  AND p.productid IN (productidList)
```

## Original Answer

So, the problem you're having is a bit difficult as it's hard to wrap my head around the original query in the first place. That said, I threw together a possible solution using inner-selects as joins to the `q_products` table. I haven't tested it, so let me know how it turns out:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
    q_products p
    JOIN (
        SELECT productid FROM q_product_apply_access paa
        WHERE paa.productid = p.productid 
          AND paa.partnerid = 'partnerid'
          AND paa.apply_status = 0
          AND p.visibility = 3
    ) paa ON paa.productid = p.productid
    JOIN (
        SELECT productid FROM q_product_aff_access paf
        WHERE paf.productid = p.productid
          AND paf.accid = 'accountid'
          AND p.visibility = 2
    ) paf ON paf.productid = p.productid
WHERE
    p.status = 0
    AND p.productId IN ( productIdList )
```

Comment: you have not mentioned `visibility=1` condition anywhere?

Comment: Hmmm.. you're right. Let me rethink this. Unfortunately, what the original query is doing is 1) getting a list of productids with a certain criteria, 2) getting more with different criteria, 3) getting more with more different criteria, and 4) unioning them into a single result set. Returning such a similiar result set using `JOIN`s is much more difficult, as a `JOIN` can't necessarily handle the disjointed filtering requirements.

Comment: UNION ALL does not ensure uniqueness; however, the different visibility values in the three branches of the UNION do ensure that the product IDs in each branch are disjoint sets.

Comment: ***DOH*** You're right Jonahtan - `UNION` ensures uniqueness, `UNION ALL` does not.

Answer (score 0):

```
INDEX(visibility, status, productid)
```

with your original `UNION ALL`

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; that may prompt other techniques.

(Edit)

After the fact, you can do

```
ALTER TABLE q_products ADD INDEX(visibility, status, productid);
```

It will take some time, depending on the size of the table.

An INDEX is usually much smaller than the table, itself.

Indexes are your first line of defense against slow queries.  (Rewriting is the second.)

How big is q_products?

Comment: I assume the `indexes` need to be created first?? I cannot afford to index each and every table as they are already very huge and i cannot compromise with size.

Answer (score 0):

Your original query, slightly reformatted, is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(q_products.productid)
  FROM q_products
 WHERE q_products.visibility = 1
   AND q_products.status = 0
   AND q_products.productid IN (productidList)
UNION  ALL 
SELECT DISTINCT(q_products.productid)
  FROM q_products, q_product_apply_access 
 WHERE q_products.productid = q_product_apply_access.productid 
   AND q_product_apply_access.partnerid = 'partnerid'
   AND q_product_apply_access.apply_status = 0 
   AND q_products.visibility = 3
   AND q_products.status = 0
   AND q_products.productid IN (productidList)
UNION  ALL
SELECT DISTINCT(q_products.productid)
  FROM q_products, q_product_aff_access 
 WHERE q_products.productid = q_product_aff_access.productid 
   AND q_product_aff_access.accid = 'accountid' 
   AND q_products.visibility = 2
   AND q_products.status = 0 
   AND q_products.productid IN (productidList)
```

You've not told us whether there are any other values for `visibility` other than `1`, `2`, `3` so we have to assume there can be other values (but note the comments below this answer).

We can see that there are some common sub-expressions restricting rows from `q_products` (`status = 0` and `productid IN (productidList)`, where it isn't clear what `productidList` really is, but we can assume it works OK.

It would be really useful if MySQL had support for CTEs (common table expressions, aka WITH clauses):

```
WITH pv AS
     (SELECT productid, visibility
        FROM q_products
       WHERE status = 0
         AND visibility IN (1, 2, 3) -- or visibility >= 1 and visibility <= 3
         AND productid IN (productidList)
     )
SELECT pv.productid
  FROM pv
 WHERE pv.visibility = 1
UNION  ALL
SELECT DISTINCT(pv.productid)
  FROM pv
  JOIN q_product_apply_access AS a
    ON pv.productid = a.productid
 WHERE pv.visibility = 3
   AND a.apply_status = 0
   AND a.partnerid = 'partnerid'
UNION  ALL
SELECT DISTINCT(pv.productid)
  FROM pv
  JOIN q_product_aff_access AS f
    ON pv.productiond = f.productid
 WHERE pv.visibility = 2
   AND f.accid = 'accountid'
```

Since MySQL doesn't yet support CTEs, you probably have to write the CTE out verbatim 3 times and hope that the optimizer spots what you're doing.  Or, since all of the alternatives are about to filter more precisely on visibility, you include that term in a modified form of the CTE (and avoid selecting `visibility` explicitly) and write it out three times — like this:

```
SELECT pv.productid
  FROM (SELECT productid
          FROM q_products
         WHERE status = 0
           AND visibility = 1
           AND productid IN (productidList)
       ) AS pv
UNION  ALL
SELECT DISTINCT(pv.productid)
  FROM (SELECT productid
          FROM q_products
         WHERE status = 0
           AND visibility = 3
           AND productid IN (productidList)
       ) AS pv
  JOIN q_product_apply_access AS a
    ON pv.productid = a.productid
 WHERE a.apply_status = 0
   AND a.partnerid = 'partnerid'
UNION  ALL
SELECT DISTINCT(pv.productid)
  FROM (SELECT productid
          FROM q_products
         WHERE status = 0
           AND visibility = 2
           AND productid IN (productidList)
       ) AS pv
  JOIN q_product_aff_access AS f
    ON pv.productiond = f.productid
 WHERE f.accid = 'accountid'
```

This should produce the same result.  It is hard to be sure that it will be faster.  It may depend on whether there are suitable indexes on the status and visibility columns of `q_products`.  The first term of the UNION could be written more simply, but this presentation is uniform with the other two alternatives, which tends to make these things clearer (to the human reading the query, and possibly to the query optimizer too).

As always, studying the actual query plan may help you improve things.

Comment: `visibility` is an `enum` object with values as only `1 , 2 and 3`, whereas productidlist is an array which consists of productids

Comment: OK.  Don't leave details like that out of your question in future.  It doesn't make a huge difference to my answer.  It simply renders the `AND visibility IN (1, 2, 3)` term in the CTE redundant (but the query optimizer might spot that and not worry about testing the condition if it knows it will always be true — no nulls to deal with, for example).  I'm more curious about the `productidList` and what that means.